# Create new assoc object in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I think this JavaScript should work, but it does not seem to. What can I do to fix it.

I am also open to other ways to do this. All I want to do is return a JSON string of the variable names (cn, sc, fn) and their values (eg. `var cn = $('#deFNIN').val();` -- so: `"cn":"MacDonalds","sc":"Mac"` )

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2m6Lpnq/1/)

```
HTML:

<input id="deCoNameIN" type="text" value="MacDonalds" /><br>
<input id="deShortCoIN" type="text" value="Macs" /><br>
<input id="deFNIN" type="text" value="Fred" /><br>

js/jQ:

var objFields = {
    'cn': { 'id':'deCoNameIN',  'required':'True',  'title':'Company Name'},
    'sc': { 'id':'deShortCoIN', 'required':'True',  'title':'Short Co name' },
    'fn': { 'id':'deFNIN',      'required':'false', 'title':'Contact first name' },
};
var arrDistinfo = [];

$.each(objFields,function(_, varname){
    tmp = $("#"+varname.id).val().trim();
    alert('Varname: ' +_+'   Val: '+tmp);
    arrDistinfo.push({_ : tmp});
});

var xx = JSON.stringify(arrDistinfo);
alert(xx);
```

The desired output should look like this:

`["cn":"Macdonalds", "cs":"Macs", "fn":"Fred"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use variables like object keys like that (in your case, `{_ : tmp}` is the same as `{"_" : tmp}`), you need the array notation:

```js
var objFields = {
  'cn': {
    'id': 'deCoNameIN',
    'required': 'True',
    'title': 'Company Name'
  },
  'sc': {
    'id': 'deShortCoIN',
    'required': 'True',
    'title': 'Short Co name'
  },
  'fn': {
    'id': 'deFNIN',
    'required': 'false',
    'title': 'Contact first name'
  },
};
var arrDistinfo = [];

$.each(objFields, function(_, varname) {
  tmp = $("#" + varname.id).val().trim();
  alert('Varname: ' + _ + '   Val: ' + tmp);
  var obj = {};
  obj[_] = tmp;
  arrDistinfo.push(obj);
});

var xx = JSON.stringify(arrDistinfo);
alert(xx);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="deCoNameIN" type="text" value="MacDonalds" />
<br>
<input id="deShortCoIN" type="text" value="Macs" />
<br>
<input id="deFNIN" type="text" value="Fred" />
<br>
```

---

UPDATE

To get that specific format, you'd need to make it a string, because JS doesn't has such array-like structure.

```js
var objFields = {
  'cn': {
    'id': 'deCoNameIN',
    'required': 'True',
    'title': 'Company Name'
  },
  'sc': {
    'id': 'deShortCoIN',
    'required': 'True',
    'title': 'Short Co name'
  },
  'fn': {
    'id': 'deFNIN',
    'required': 'false',
    'title': 'Contact first name'
  },
};
var arrDistinfo = {};

$.each(objFields, function(_, varname) {
  tmp = $("#" + varname.id).val().trim();
  arrDistinfo[_] = tmp;
});

var output = [];
for (var i in arrDistinfo) {
  output.push('"' + i + '":"' + arrDistinfo[i] + '"'); 
}

alert('[' + output.join(', ') + ']');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input id="deCoNameIN" type="text" value="MacDonalds" />
    <br>
    <input id="deShortCoIN" type="text" value="Macs" />
    <br>
    <input id="deFNIN" type="text" value="Fred" />
    <br>
```

Comment: That produces output like this: `[{"cn":"Macdonalds"},{"cs":"Macs"},{"fn":"Fred"}]`.  What if I want it to look like this: `["cn":"Macdonalds", "cs":"Macs", "fn":"Fred"]` ?  (I've updated question to reflect -- sorry I wasn't clear earlier)

Comment: You'd have to make it a string that looks like that. There are no associative arrays in JS like in, say, PHP.

Comment: Shomz, thank you very very much. Exactly what I need. Upvote ^ 77.   As it turns out, though, I was on the right track -- [see this updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2m6Lpnq/3/).  Without your example, I never would have figured out the solution: `var arrDistinfo = {};` instead of `var arrDistinfo = []`

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! :)  Yes, you had a problem with keys using the standard arrays, but I'm sure you'll never make the same mistake.